# WebStorm 2023.1.2 doesn't recognize defineProps, defineEmits, computed etc. in a TypeScript project in Nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, webstorm

As the headline says, I've programming on a Nuxt 3 project with TypeScript & `<script setup>` composition API syntax. The project has a standardized `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["@types/node"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

But WebStorm in its 2023.1.2 version still throws errors at auto-imported composition API functions with the error message:

> Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json

Whats wrong here, what can I do to fix it?

I added a standardized ts.json config and setup the project as typical, it shouldn't have errors here.

Comment: There is no WebStorm version 2023.2.1. Latest version is 2023.1.2 and 2023.2 is currently in EAP. Also it sounds more like a bug or feature request which should be raised in their issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Thats true, typo, sorry. Maybe it's a bug but as of the blog posts from them, the 2023 version should pick them up. But i'm not sure if its a problem with WebStorm cause Visual Studio Code doesn't get them either.

Comment: Sometimes I like to use older versions/releases of WebStorm. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, using Typescript v4 instead of v5 worked for me. It seems like it’s a bug of WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Had the same problem with defineProps and *Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json* message. A Vite.js based project with standard TypeScript config. The problem did not interfere the bulding process, just an annoying warning and lack of auto-completion in IDE. Intellij Idea 2022.2

### Solution

The issue may be fixed by adding the reference to the definition of the `defineProps` function in the tsconfig.json. For Vue 3.3 the sample is below

```
{
  //... tsconfig.json
  "files": ["node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.d.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Trying to migrate from Nuxt 2

I did not recognize I was using an old `tsconfig.json`. Removing the complete `exclude` config resolved this.

```json
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".nuxt",
    "dist"
  ]
```

**Add excluded paths one by one again**

Using Webstorm 2023.3